# Fabric Android: login with Twitter and Callback URL

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-fabric

I'm integrating Fabrick SDK in an Android app which has also a Backend to interact with a REST API. This Backend API should be secured, and in the past in other projects (not Android apps) I used both Twitter and Facebook OAuth logins with a calback URL that redirects to my Backend. From there I generate a custom auth token that must be used from the client (in this case, my Android app) to interact with my own API.

The thing is that I've been trying to call a callback URL somehow using Fabric but I could not. I've read the documentation and...

https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/configure1

"(...) Callback URL
Although Fabric will ignore the value of the callback URL, it must be set to a valid URL for the app to work with the SDK. (...)"

Does anyone know why is that? There exists any other Twitter API request call accessible from Fabric's Twitter kit to specify a callback URL instead of using the Twitter sign one? There must be a solution for that because most of the developers that uses Twitter for medium to complex software projects including authentication must deal with this kind of problem for sure, but I found nothing.

Regards,

Luis Cappa

Answer (score 2):

Since very recently you have to add `twittersdk://` to your app in apps.twitter.com if using Android - twitterkit.

See https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/issues/135#issuecomment-397395425

Background info https://twittercommunity.com/t/action-required-sign-in-with-twitter-users-must-whitelist-callback-urls/105342

Answer (score 0):

Just list is as your site.

```
http://www.yourhomepage.com
```

Twitter supports multiple types of authentication, if it is a regular O-Auth Request, you can just use your site as a placeholder.

See here: https://twittercommunity.com/t/callback-url/398/14

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I have already configured both homepage and callback URL in my Twitter application, but the callback is never called. I'm using TwitterLoginButton + TwitterAuthConfig to call the Twitter login form after the button is clicked, just as the Fabric tutorial says. I know, because I've done in the past, that if you call 'manually' the Twitter login request one of the available parameters to specify is the callback URL and is redirected to it. Anyway, this problem is specific of Fabric SDK for Twitter login.